# remove attribute value using xpath and lxml python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm using the following code to access attribute value in xml file and remove it

```
import lxml.etree as et
def ignore_xpath(xmlFile,xpath):
    tree = et.parse(xmlFile)
    for elt in tree.xpath(xpath):
        elt='' 
    print et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

but that doesn't work for xpath: `/root/@attribute`

What am I doing wrong and how can I know if my `elt` is an attribute or a tag (case xpath= `/root[@attribute]`)? I want to treat them differently.

Comment: Show your xml. Also, you if you select `/@attribute` you will get an attribute list, so not need to additionally look if it is a tag or an attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..my xml file is not special what I want to do is that if the given xpath indicates an attribute my function should replace it's value with '' : for example if my xml file is like : <root attribute="hello"/> and xpath is : /root/@hello I want to find a way to transform it into <root attribute=""/>

Comment: Did my answer help? If yes, please accept it. If not, what was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove an attribute that you selected. You have to select the elements (tags) that contain that attribute. I'm going to assume your document is the following:

```
<root attribute="something"/>
```

You can then do the following:

```
for elt in tree.xpath("/root"):
    elt.set("attribute", "")
print et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

When you do `elt = ''`, you just replace the reference, but not the actual attribute.